# Looking for IoT device for an unmanned site so customers can send a support email

Tags: wireless, remote-control

I am looking for an industrial-grade device that would allow a customer at an unmanned fuel site to push a button that would send an email to the IT department, in the event that there is an error code on the dispenser. The connection would be made available by a hot spot that is being used to process transactions. Any ideas?

Thank you